# FindMaximum wont give the correct solution

Tags: mathematical-optimization

So i have this function for witch i made a 3D plot and tried to do a `FindMaximum[func,{x,0},{y,0.45}]]`search for coordinates `x=0` and `y=0.45` because it looks like the maximum is in that proximity but it gives me some ludicrous resaults that cant be right.If i just do `func/.x->0/.y->0.45` it gives a value in the expected range.The range for x and y is 0 to 1.
The function looks like this

```
func=(36 (-((
           4849678413722143149839946135 ((7 x^2)/5 - (12 x^3)/5 + 
              x^4) (-9 y + 12 y^2))/28326208592086409437597807496) + (
          10701629009321335947586202445 ((16 x^2)/5 - (21 x^3)/5 + 
             x^5) (-9 y + 12 y^2))/28326208592086409437597807496 + (
          302721643448438464893982092105 ((7 x^2)/5 - (12 x^3)/5 + 
             x^4) (-12 y + 20 y^3))/453219337473382551001564919936 - (
          9276785765744257133881114365 ((16 x^2)/5 - (21 x^3)/5 + 
             x^5) (-12 y + 20 y^3))/16186404909763662535770175712 + (
          5304264590147948993897932317 ((27 x^2)/5 - (32 x^3)/5 + 
             x^6) (-15 y + 30 y^4))/56652417184172818875195614992 - (
          139779071359314865060733865 (8 x^2 - 9 x^3 + x^7) (-18 y + 
             42 y^5))/16186404909763662535770175712)^2 + 
       108 (-((4849678413722143149839946135 ((14 x)/5 - (36 x^2)/5 + 
              4 x^3) (1/2 - (9 y^2)/2 + 4 y^3))/
           28326208592086409437597807496) + (
          10701629009321335947586202445 ((32 x)/5 - (63 x^2)/5 + 
             5 x^4) (1/2 - (9 y^2)/2 + 4 y^3))/
          28326208592086409437597807496 + (
          302721643448438464893982092105 ((14 x)/5 - (36 x^2)/5 + 
             4 x^3) (1 - 6 y^2 + 5 y^4))/
          453219337473382551001564919936 - (
          9276785765744257133881114365 ((32 x)/5 - (63 x^2)/5 + 
             5 x^4) (1 - 6 y^2 + 5 y^4))/16186404909763662535770175712 + (
          5304264590147948993897932317 ((54 x)/5 - (96 x^2)/5 + 6 x^5) (3/
             2 - (15 y^2)/2 + 6 y^5))/56652417184172818875195614992 - (
          139779071359314865060733865 (16 x - 27 x^2 + 7 x^6) (2 - 
             9 y^2 + 7 y^6))/16186404909763662535770175712)^2 - 
       36 (-((4849678413722143149839946135 ((7 x^2)/5 - (12 x^3)/5 + 
              x^4) (-9 y + 12 y^2))/28326208592086409437597807496) + (
          10701629009321335947586202445 ((16 x^2)/5 - (21 x^3)/5 + 
             x^5) (-9 y + 12 y^2))/28326208592086409437597807496 + (
          302721643448438464893982092105 ((7 x^2)/5 - (12 x^3)/5 + 
             x^4) (-12 y + 20 y^3))/453219337473382551001564919936 - (
          9276785765744257133881114365 ((16 x^2)/5 - (21 x^3)/5 + 
             x^5) (-12 y + 20 y^3))/16186404909763662535770175712 + (
          5304264590147948993897932317 ((27 x^2)/5 - (32 x^3)/5 + 
             x^6) (-15 y + 30 y^4))/56652417184172818875195614992 - (
          139779071359314865060733865 (8 x^2 - 9 x^3 + x^7) (-18 y + 
             42 y^5))/
          16186404909763662535770175712) (-((
           4849678413722143149839946135 (14/5 - (72 x)/5 + 12 x^2) (y/
              2 - (3 y^3)/2 + y^4))/28326208592086409437597807496) + (
          10701629009321335947586202445 (32/5 - (126 x)/5 + 20 x^3) (y/
             2 - (3 y^3)/2 + y^4))/28326208592086409437597807496 + (
          302721643448438464893982092105 (14/5 - (72 x)/5 + 12 x^2) (y - 
             2 y^3 + y^5))/453219337473382551001564919936 - (
          9276785765744257133881114365 (32/5 - (126 x)/5 + 20 x^3) (y - 
             2 y^3 + y^5))/16186404909763662535770175712 + (
          5304264590147948993897932317 (54/5 - (192 x)/5 + 30 x^4) ((3 y)/
             2 - (5 y^3)/2 + y^6))/56652417184172818875195614992 - (
          139779071359314865060733865 (16 - 54 x + 42 x^5) (2 y - 3 y^3 + 
             y^7))/16186404909763662535770175712) + 
       36 (-((4849678413722143149839946135 (14/5 - (72 x)/5 + 12 x^2) (y/
              2 - (3 y^3)/2 + y^4))/28326208592086409437597807496) + (
          10701629009321335947586202445 (32/5 - (126 x)/5 + 20 x^3) (y/
             2 - (3 y^3)/2 + y^4))/28326208592086409437597807496 + (
          302721643448438464893982092105 (14/5 - (72 x)/5 + 12 x^2) (y - 
             2 y^3 + y^5))/453219337473382551001564919936 - (
          9276785765744257133881114365 (32/5 - (126 x)/5 + 20 x^3) (y - 
             2 y^3 + y^5))/16186404909763662535770175712 + (
          5304264590147948993897932317 (54/5 - (192 x)/5 + 30 x^4) ((3 y)/
             2 - (5 y^3)/2 + y^6))/56652417184172818875195614992 - (
          139779071359314865060733865 (16 - 54 x + 42 x^5) (2 y - 3 y^3 + 
             y^7))/16186404909763662535770175712)^2)^0.5
Plot3D[func, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> Full]  
FindMaximum[func, {{x, 0}, {y, 0.45}}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give a constraint for the range x,y you can solve your problem:

```
FindMaximum[{func, 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1}, {{x, 0}, {y, 0.45}}]
(*{0.658277, {x -> 7.30777*10^-9, y -> 0.440418}}*)
```

alternatively without starting points

```
NMaximize[{func, 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1}, {x, y}]
(* {0.658277, {x -> -3.97487*10^-27, y -> 0.440418}} *)
```